# Plotly.js Bar Chart data argument is not assignable to parameter of type 'Data[]'

Tags: javascript, angular, bar-chart, pie-chart, plotly.js

I am new to plotly and I'm currently trying to replicate a straight forward bar chart : [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/ai/tryit.asp?filename=tryai_plotly_bars).

I have created an angular component for the same and I installed the package via: `npm i --save plotly.js-dist-min`

Here is the code:

```
var xArray = ["Italy", "France", "Spain", "USA", "Argentina"];
var yArray = [55, 49, 44, 24, 15];

var data = [{
  x:xArray,
  y:yArray,
  type: "bar"
}];

var layout = {title:"World Wide Wine Production"};

Plotly.newPlot("bars", data, layout);
```

The error goes away when I remove `type: "bar"`. However, I get a line chart when type is removed.

and the error displayed is:

> Argument of type '{ x: string[]; y: number[]; type: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Data[]'.
> Type '{ x: string[]; y: number[]; type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Data'.
> Type '{ x: string[]; y: number[]; type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial'.
> Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"violin" | undefined'.
>
> ```
>  Plotly.newPlot("my_bars", data, layout);
> ```

I get a similar error for `type: pie` :

> error TS2345: Argument of type '{ labels: string[]; values: number[]; type: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Data[]'.
> Type '{ labels: string[]; values: number[]; type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Data'.
> Type '{ labels: string[]; values: number[]; type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial'.
> Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"pie" | undefined'.
>
> ```
>  Plotly.newPlot("my_pie", data, layout);
> ```